# JS await only valid in async function. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell me I defined a function as async but still it not working and throwing error How can I resolve this issue?

```js
var courses = [
    {ID: 1, Name: 'course 1', Author: 'Mariela Mckinney', Website: 'www.loarpharei.com'},
    {ID: 2, Name: 'course 2', Author: 'Brylee Becker', Website: 'www.phattiodye.com'},
    {ID: 3, Name: 'course 3', Author: 'Weston Edwards', Website: 'www.pretathlew.com'},
    {ID: 4, Name: 'course 4', Author: 'Nathanael Fox', Website: 'www.senfredral.com'},
    {ID: 5, Name: 'course 5', Author: 'Aarav Park', Website: 'www.ebreanerin.com'}
]

async function get_course(ID){
    return setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('I am fired');
        return get_index(ID);
    }, 2000);
}

let course_id = await get_course(2);
console.log(course_id);
```

Comment: [Minimum effort](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SyntaxError%3A+await+is+only+valid+in+async+function) please.

Comment: Basic google search to understand async/await might help. https://codeburst.io/javascript-es-2017-learn-async-await-by-example-48acc58bad65

Comment: Not the function you want to wait for must be marked `async`, but the function in which something is `await`ed.

Answer (score 2):

There are many mistakes in the code. I hope the snippet helps you.

```js
const courses = [
  {id: 1, name: 'course 1', author: 'Mariela Mckinney', website: 'www.loarpharei.com'},
  {id: 2, name: 'course 2', author: 'Brylee Becker', website: 'www.phattiodye.com'},
  {id: 3, name: 'course 3', author: 'Weston Edwards', website: 'www.pretathlew.com'},
  {id: 4, name: 'course 4', author: 'Nathanael Fox', website: 'www.senfredral.com'},
  {id: 5, name: 'course 5', author: 'Aarav Park', website: 'www.ebreanerin.com'},
]

// The "async" keyword is actually redundant if there is no "await" keyword in
// the function.
async function getCourse(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('I am fired');
      resolve(courses[id]);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function main() {
  // You can always "await" an Async function, or a function returning a Promise.
  const course = await getCourse(2);
  console.log(course);
}

main();

// Notes:
// 1. Always use camelCase for field names, function names and variable names.
// 2. Most JavaScript developers prefer 2-space indent, instead of 4.
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `await` outside of an `async` function. It is how the API is designed. See the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await:

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

If you want to use `await` you need to wrap

```
let course_id = await get_course(2);
```

inside an `async` function.

Also, as Daniel A. White pointed out, `setTimeout` doesn't return a `Promise`, but a timer ID that you can later use to cancel the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You could use IIFE to wrap your await call in `async` function but you also need return promise from other function.

```js
var courses = [{ID: 1, Name: 'course 1', Author: 'Mariela Mckinney', Website: 'www.loarpharei.com'},{ID: 2, Name: 'course 2', Author: 'Brylee Becker', Website: 'www.phattiodye.com'},{ID: 3, Name: 'course 3', Author: 'Weston Edwards', Website: 'www.pretathlew.com'},{ID: 4, Name: 'course 4', Author: 'Nathanael Fox', Website: 'www.senfredral.com'},{ID: 5, Name: 'course 5', Author: 'Aarav Park', Website: 'www.ebreanerin.com'}]

function get_course(ID) {
  console.log('I am fired.')
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(courses)
    }, 2000)
  })
}

(async() => {
  let course_id = await get_course(2);
  console.log(course_id);
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` doesn't return a promise. You have to wrap it in a `new Promise(...)` call. The `get_course(2)` call is just a free/floating call that isn't inside of any function, so `await` wont work there.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap you setTimeout into Promise. see the example:

```js
 (async() => {var courses = [
   {ID: 1, Name: 'course 1', Author: 'Mariela Mckinney', Website: 'www.loarpharei.com'},
   {ID: 2, Name: 'course 2', Author: 'Brylee Becker', Website: 'www.phattiodye.com'},
   {ID: 3, Name: 'course 3', Author: 'Weston Edwards', Website: 'www.pretathlew.com'},
   {ID: 4, Name: 'course 4', Author: 'Nathanael Fox', Website: 'www.senfredral.com'},
   {ID: 5, Name: 'course 5', Author: 'Aarav Park', Website: 'www.ebreanerin.com'}
 ]
 
 function get_index(id) {
   return courses.findIndex(i => i.ID === id);
 }

 function get_course(ID){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('I am fired');
        resolve(get_index(ID));
   }, 2000);
   });
 }

 let course_id = await get_course(2);
 console.log(course_id);
})();
```